# How to set root view controller of window to a UINavingationController when current root view controller of window is UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UITabBarController` which contains four navigation controllers.
When user taps a button , I want to set the root `viewController` of window to a new navigation controller.
How do I do that in Objective-C?

Comment: That sounds like a very jarring transition.  Could you consider a different approach, like presenting the navigation controller as a modal view controller?

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for answering. Sorry I'm newbie in ios programming. i want to know the suitable approach for that workflow. How to implement?

Comment: Are you talking about the tab bar buttons or buttons contained in views managed by the four navigation controllers?

Comment: I have a uitabbarcontroller where each tab is a uinavigation controller. in tab1 currently a uiviewcontroller is active which contains a button in its nav bar. when user clicks on that bar i want to show an entirely different UIViewcontroller which is independent of the current workflow. how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Using a modal view controller will look better than simply replacing the root view controller, and should produce the same effect as you are looking for.  Basically, you create an instance of your view controller, add it to a new navigation controller, and then present the navigation controller modally:

```
- (void)buttonPressed
{
    MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```